# How to post something on Facebook that doesn't drop down with the timeline?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to post a message on Facebook -  "See my new webpage at www.mypage.com" where www.mypage.com is clickable.  But I want it to stay prominent at the top of the page.  I don't want to have to repeat it every day to keep it on  top.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

---

- emphasized text

***No that only work on page(like) or groups